# Simple linq query gives errors

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, process

I m programming in c# and I use the following lines in my code to sort processes by id using linq as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2f5289e7-6be6-4ef5-800a-5067eeb501a5):

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
var sorted = from p in processes orderby p.Id descending select p;
```

I added System.Core reference to my project and also added using System.Linq in the relevant cs file.

But it gives me errors saying ';' are expected and invalid term 'in' etc.
This s my fist query in linq and how to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: The code is fine, are you sure you don't have a missing ; elsewhere?

Comment: do you still get the error if you comment out the 2 lines?

Comment: @devdigital: No, other places are ok, and it points to the 2nd line above.

Comment: you also have to add 'using System.Diagnostics;' for Process

Comment: @sacklpicka: I get no errors when they are commented out....

Comment: @hcb: Yeah, I ve already added that...

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me, with `using System.Linq` and adding a System.core reference.  Make sure if you use it in a sub-project, that you also add System.core there. In your project Properties, maybe check your framework version?  I think it was added in c# 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Which vs version are you using ? I tried your code in vs2008 with .NET Framework 3.5, and it worked fine without giving any errors.

Comment: VS2005 doesn't support LINQ syntax - you need VS2008 or above for that.